# How to output pyspark logs to a file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to send the logs from pyspark to a file. I've looked at countless questions here with no success. I am using python 3.7 with pysaprk 2.4.7.

I get the logger using:

```
    log4j_logger = spark_session.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j
    spark_logger = log4j_logger.LogManager.getRootLogger()
```

The `spark_logger` is of type `org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger` so I proceed to add a file appended "java style" using pyjnius:

```
rolling_appender = autoclass("org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender")
appender = rolling_appender()
appender.setFile(str(self._log_file))
appender.activateOptions()
spark_logger.addAppender(appender)
```

But I get this error:

```
  File "*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in _build_args
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in <listcomp>
    [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
  File "*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
    command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
AttributeError: 'org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

I know the spark logger is fetched successfully because I can log to it and it will appear in the console.

Any easier way (that works lol) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I was able to do it using an appender from log4j.

```
    log4j = self._spark_session.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.log4j

    spark_logger = log4j.LogManager.getLogger("org.apache.spark")

    appender = log4j.RollingFileAppender()
    appender.setAppend(True)
    layout = log4j.PatternLayout()
    layout.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n")
    appender.setLayout(layout)
    appender.setFile(str(self._log_file))
    appender.activateOptions()

    spark_logger.removeAllAppenders()
    spark_logger.addAppender(appender)
```